# Return something that is not a part of any model in Generics.listAPIView

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

How do you format data returned from the Generics.ListAPIView class before sending it to the front end? I want to add metadata to the return value, but I can't add any metadata that isn't already part of a model. For instance:

```
class someList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = someSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return someQueryset()

class someListSerializer(SurveySerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = someListModel
        fields = ['modelField']

class someListModel(Base):
    modelField=models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
```

This would yield
[{modelField:information},{modelField:information},{modelField:information}]

What if I want
[
{modelField:information, informationCalculatedFromQueryset:butNotPartOfModel}, {modelField:information, informationCalculatedFromQueryset:butNotPartOfModel},{modelField:information, informationCalculatedFromQueryset:butNotPartOfModel}
]

informationCalculatedFromQueryset is not part of someListModel, so I can't just add it into fields. How do I manually append this information to the front end? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use  [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) in this you can do like this:

```py
    class SurveySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        otherField = serializers.SerailzerMethodField()

        get_otherField(self, obj):
             return "I am other field"
    
        class Meta:
              model = Survey
              fields = "__all__"
```